# Error: Cannot run demisto.executeCommand() from integrations

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting error when i tried to execute xsoar demisto command from integrations, the command is working when i execute it from automation script, but it is not working for integration

i am expecting that is there any way to run that command from integration or call automation script from integration

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Seems duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74542663/how-to-run-demisto-executecommand-from-integrations