# How to Run demisto.executeCommand() from integrations

Tags: python, python-3.x, integration

Actually i want help regarding executing command i.e (demisto.executeCommand) for getting saved incidents from xsoar server but i am unable to do that, i am getting exception that i can't fire demisto.executeCommand from integrations, same command is working from automation scripts.

```
Error: Script failed to run: 
Error: [Traceback (most recent call last):
   
   File "<string>", line 350, in <module>
   File "<string>", line 343, in main
   File "<string>", line 7807, in return_error
 Exception: Failed to execute fetch-incidents command.
Error:
'Demisto' object has no attribute 'executeCommand'
] (2604) (2603)
```

I am executing it from XSoar IDE[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViCLM.png)

I am expecting that when i will fire command from integration i should get the result, what i get running it using automation script xsoar IDE

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As per [XSOAR docs](https://xsoar.pan.dev/docs/reference/api/demisto-class#executecommand), the executeCommand method is only available for scripts (automations). Therefore, you can't use it on an integration.